# How can I add C++ Libraries (e.g. libjpeg-dev) into Windows Docker Image so that CMake can detect them?

Tags: docker, cmake, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I'm setting up a Windows docker container in order to be able to compile a CMake C++ project. The CMake files grab the packages using the `find_package()` CMake command. For example:

```
find_package(JPEG CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
find_package(PNG CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(ZLIB CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

Now installing these libraries on a linux docker container was pretty simple, I just had to add a line to the 'CORE_PACKAGES'. Here's an example of what my linux dockerfile looks like.

```
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 \
    PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 \
    CORE_PACKAGES="\
        # ... other trivial packages omitted  
        libjpeg-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
    "

# Install core dependencies & updates
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade && \
    apt-get install -y $CORE_PACKAGES && \
    update-ca-certificates
```

I'm trying to create the equivalent of this snippet in a Windows dockerfile.
In my Windows dockerfile, I'm using a windows package manager called 'Choco' to install some things on windows, but Choco doesn't have things like 'libpng-dev' and 'libjpeg-dev'. So my question is, what is the standard practice for adding C++ Dev libraries on a Windows Docker container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot more research on different C++ Package Managers that are compatible on Windows and Linux, I came across [VcPkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) and highly recommend it to others who are looking for a c++ package manager.

Here are some features that I found particularly useful

- CMake compatible
- Easy installation via script, making it very easy to add to a docker container
- Compatible with Windows, Linux, and Mac
- Tons of C++ packages, and if one doesn't exist, you can open an issue to have it be added, or you can implement it yourself and open a pull request
- Open source

The only downside to using Vcpkg is that there's no native way to choose an older version of a certain package.